# Java Arrays.binary search returns wrong data even when array is sorted

Tags: java

The documentation writes that "Arrays.binarySearch return a.length if all elements in the array are less than the specified key." So in the following program, I am expecting the value 4 to be printed but it prints -4. Why this anomalous behaviour?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Main{ 
    public static void main(String[] args)throws java.lang.Exception{
        int[] a = new int[3];
        a[0] = 3;
        a[1] = 8;
        a[2] = 9;
        System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(a, 15));         
    }
}
```

Comment: For this kind of questions, the answer is always in the docs.

Comment: @MarounMaroun To be fair, this time the issue is that the poster misread the docs, instead of just not looking at all.

Comment: @DennisMeng Now I feel bad :(

Comment: It doesn't say that at all. Read it again. Nowhere does it say it 'returns a.length'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoting from [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28byte%5B%5D,%20byte%29)..

> Returns: index of the search key, if it is contained in the array; otherwise,
>   (-(insertion point) - 1).

where the insertion point is

> defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the
>   array: the index of the first element greater than the key, or
>   a.length if all elements in the array are less than the specified key

In your example, all elements are less than `15` and length of the array is `3`. So the insertion point is `3` and therefore binarySearch returns `-3-1 = -4`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's returning a negative value it's not found:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

public static int binarySearch(Object[] a,
                               Object key)

Returns: index of the search key, if it is contained in the array; otherwise, (-(insertion point) - 1). The insertion point is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the array: the index of the first element greater than the key, or a.length if all elements in the array are less than the specified key. Note that this guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the key is found.